# What's the best way to build a FF add-on that automatically detects and downloads mp3s from a website?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

This is my first FF Addon but I'm familiar with JS and made a few Chrome Extensions before. The documentation and tutorials I've found online are old and I'm uncertain if they're up to date with best practices and techniques. Also it appears there are 2 ways to create FF extensions..

1. Traditional, classic, or XUL
2. Restartless, or bootstrapped extensions, using Add-on SDK or Add-on Builder.

So... Which of these 2 is the best method for creating an extension? The extension will detect mp3s streaming on X website, then auto download and save them to my HD.

Also any tips, tools for a newbie would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see a comparison here: [SDK and XUL Comparison](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-22/dev-guide/guides/sdk-vs-xul.html).

For your specific case i don't think you need a very complicated addon, so it looks like addon-sdk is better suited for your needs. And if you already developed a few chrome extensions, you will be more familiarized with it too.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try exploring down the SDK route then. Gracias.